# Dropdown select to match selected value after refresh

Tags: php, html

Basically, I have a dropdown box that submits its value to PHP that exists in the same document using GET. So in effect, once the value is submitted the page is refreshed. The dropdown box then jumps back to its default selection.

How can I keep the selection the same even though the page has been refreshed?

Comment: You can record the current selection at the time of refresh, and then pass that value back to the element as the selected option...

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep record of what was selected. There are different ways of doing it, for example a quick fix would be to pass data to the php file itself using get and have an if statement which will add the value of "selected" to your dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

When echo-ing your `option` tags, check the value of the current item against the value of the selected one (assuming you create a variable containing the selection called `$selectedItem`). Something like this:

```
<?php foreach ($items as $item) { ?>
    <option value="<?= $item ?>" <?php if ($item == $selectedItem) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>><?= $item ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you link to the same page that you are on, instead of linking to "myPage.php", link to `myPage.php?selectedValue=".$selectedValue`

So then, you could right off the bat check for this value and determine the state.

```
<?php
   $mySelection = $_GET['selectedValue'];
   if($mySelection == NULL) {
     //Display your typical dropdown
   } else {
     echo "<select>";
     echo "<option value=".$mySelection." selected></option>";
     echo "</select>";
   }
?>
```